# regex for float with 6 decimals and 3 numbers

Tags: regex, floating-point, decimal

I need a regex for a float number positive or negative with a maximum of 3 numbers before the decimal separator and 6 (only 6) numbers after.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does that mean trailing zeroes?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Also do you just need to match them? or format them? - like pad them out with zeroes when need?

Comment: ALSO : which regex "flavour"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript - this will match what you want. But without further clarification there's nothing more to be done:

```
/[+|-][0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{6}/g
```

Cheers.

Comment: n.b. this handles explicit plus signs and the negative symbol.

Comment: its perfect!Thank you...i just need a little change...i don't need to handle the explicit plus signs and the negative change

Comment: /[-]{0,1}[0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{6}/g should fix it. if it works, please go ahead and hit that "tick answer" :)

Comment: /-?[0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]{6}/g even better.

Comment: sorry, i have another question (i'm really a newbie with regex) i need the regex above to accept also integer number (so not only 6 decimals but also 5,4,3,2,1 and 0)

Comment: Sounds like this is what you want? - /^-?[0-9]{0,3}(\.[0-9]{0,6})?$/   be aware that it might also match an empty String... what is the minimum that it should have?

Answer (score 0):

It's Perl regex flavour.

For java script : `/[+|-]\d{1,3}\.\d{6}/`

For java : `"[+|-]\\d{1,3}\.\\d{6}"` /* Use pattern and matcher in java.util.regex.*/